# JQuery not working in seperate .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having an issue with my JQuery code.

When I add this code in script tags on my HTML file, it will work, however when I place it in a separate js file, it will not work. I know it's not an issue with referencing the correct file name and location.

Here is my code:

```
//Populate date select options
var num = [i];
var by = '<option value="2009">2009</option>'
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var lst = "";
var lst1 = "";
var lst2 = "";
var i;
for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    lst = lst + '<option value="' + i + '">' + months[i-1] + '</option>';
} 
for (i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
    num.push(i);
    lst1 = lst1 + '<option value="' + i + '">' + num[i] + '</option>';
}
for (i = 10; i <= 30; i++) {
    num.push(i);
    lst2 = lst2 + '<option value="20' + i + '">20' + num[i] + '</option>';
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#month").html(lst);
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#day").html(lst1);
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#year").html(by + lst2);
});
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Are you including it after jQuery? The only difference between javascript in a script tag and in a file is that the browser has to wait for the file to load before executing it. Either you're not including it in the right place or it's not being referenced correctly (sometimes this is because of cache issues).

Answer (score 1):

Referencing the file depends on the folder hierarchy. Please check that as well, and if possible share the html file.

Check in your browser whether the separate js file is included, if yes but a break-point inside one of the '$(document).ready' function